# Label a shapefile from command line

Tags: qgis, gdal, windows

I have a SHP file and a DBF file that has an attribute table with a column for elevation.  Through command line how can I make this these elevations visible when I view the shapefile?

I would like to overlay a shapefile over map to create a topographic map.

I do not want to do this using a GUI.

Update:
I would like to use the tools provided with OSGeo.  This for example is what I want but I'm doing it through QGIS GUI.  Blue is my shapefile, it then created labels (in black) based on my DBF.  I'm pretty sure QGIS uses GRASS commands but I am unsure of how to do this.

[image]

I have a file with lots of data like below, but I don't know how to actually overlay it over my shapefile.

[image]

Comment: This is a bit unclear: is your shapefile *points*? where is your base map coming from? how are you viewing your shape file? what has the qgis tag got to do with it?

Comment: @Spacedman I'm currently viewing the shapefile in QGIS.  I guess overall I would just like to overlay the shapefile with the DBF info (as shown above) over top of another image.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MapServer](http://mapserver.org) with the following workflow:

1. create a [mapfile](http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/) with the elevation layer (and its labels/annotations) and your basemap(s) ([basemaps](https://github.com/mapserver/basemaps), for example)
2. invoke the [`shp2img`](http://mapserver.org/utilities/shp2img.html) command like `shp2img -m foo.map -l "elevation basemap" -o bar.png`

The output will be an image graphic depicting the elevation shapefile with annotations atop a basemap layer.